# Can one change their destiny from which is there in astrological predictions?

Tags: astrology, horoscopes

Sometimes astrological predictions(Jathakam) is entirely bad thought out the life. Some astrologers tell this person's life is always doomed.

Can he/she change it in the present life itself by doing good karmas?

Comment: Destiny can be changed through devotion to Paramatma and engaged in Yoga. Here first step in yoga is to follow Dharma. The more you follow Dharma, Karma's pain and reactions will slowly subside and thereby destiny can be changed

Comment: @AkshayS If a person is good by hear he/she need not to worry about the effects of planets right?

Comment: what do you mean by "good" - my definition is - only who surrenders to Paramatma, worship him or worship regularly the deities which they have in house, proper chanting of mantras, following Dharma - for them alone planets wont work. Even if you are good in today, but irregular in worship of deities, dont have knowledge of karmas, you would still be influenced by planets!

Comment: @AkshayS yes for a devotee planets have no effects right?

Comment: I cant give a common concrete answer because it varies with indvidual mind of person. But yes a yogi has no planets influence on him but that stage can be reached gradually only... Cant happen immediately!

Comment: if i do japa of particular Goddess or God  everyday, or reaching a specific count- of the moolamantra of - like Bhadrakaali or Lord SriKrishna or Rudra , will my destiny change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Astavakra Samhita* 1.11 says (Swami Nityaswarupananda translator):

> He who considers himself free is free indeed, and he who considers himself bound remains bound. 'As one thinks, so one becomes' is a popular saying in this world, and it is quite true.

If you think you cannot change your karma, you cannot. If you think you can, you can.

Comment: I wanted to contact you regarding the fact that the while questions indirectly insulting Swamiji get so many upvotes, the answers supporting Swamiji get nil or few upvotes and many downvotes !! But so many keep Swamiji's picture as profile image!   There must be some problem somewhere.Secterianism, bigotry and dogmatism raising their heads repeatedly.